# Transforming a Wireless Computer Mouse into a Wireless Switch

Tags: electrical-engineering, wireless-communication, frequency-response

With no computer involved whatsoever, I want to be able to read oscillator outputs from my wireless mouse and switch an LED on a left click AND off on a right click. I have taken my mouse apart to try and understand the parts but overall I am stuck on how to approach transforming my usb receiver for this.

How would I go about using the USB receiver and interpreting it’s outputs.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a ['Naive design' question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/188/1832). Such questions are excessively broad and are therefore not a good fit for our format. See if you can [edit] your question to make it specific and answerable.

Comment: For starters I would share some of the internal of the mouse in consideration. Can you describe the oscillator output referenced in the question? Do you have any block diagrams?

Comment: "*How would I go about using the USB receiver and interpreting it’s outputs?*" With a computer. You'll need a microcontroller at the least and that's a computer of sorts.